# Create and start "edit user profile" intent successfully

Tags: android, android-intent

I've built an application that requires a user to have a profile on the device in order to perform certain functions. I am able to successfully launch a contact editing activity with the intent below to prompt the user to create the user profile:

```
//todo:prompt user to enter profile information
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Create a new profile"));
```

The problem is that the activity appears to finish immediately after being launched. I tried removing the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag and using different Uris to test. There is no problem editing a user profile that already exists on the device by using the QuickContactBadge in combination with the user profile Uri. I might be missing something obvious but I can't seem to pin it down. The logs show nothing out of the ordinary. No errors. No exceptions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional info:

Target device: genymotion-google_nexus_5___5_0_0___api_21___1080x1920-192.168.56.102:5555

Comment: Tried using "ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT" as the intent action with the same result :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being use Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT as the action.